# Gnome keyboard shortcuts dysfunctional after waking up from sleep

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, gnome

I am using Ubuntu 9.10 on my Thinkpad T61. Very often after the system **woke up from sleep**, all the gnome shortcuts went dead (no effect when key combinations pressed).

Things like "Alt+F4, Alt+TAB" are dead; things like Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V are OK; buttons such as volume up/down also OK;

I tried to Google for answers but wasn't lucky enough. Any idea how to solve it? 
Thanks!

If it's not preventable, can I at least restore them without restarting the session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and run `xev` before and after the suspend, and press various of the key combinations that work/don't work. Log the results to separate files. You should see the key presses (even of keys like `Alt` etc) coming through. Then you should be able to see exactly what's changed when the problem occurs. With that info you can file a handy bug on `bugs.launchpad.net` and somebody should pick it up and help you diagnose what's wrong